# Sync Sims 4 saves across multiple computers?

Tags: the-sims-4

I play The Sims 4 on both my laptop and my computer, however my progress on either of these is not reflected on the other. Is there any easy way to do this within Windows or is there a way to enable cloud saving?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately The Sims 4 does not feature cloud saving. This means that any progress made on one computer is not carried over to another computer, even when you are logged into your Steam or Origin account.

A solid way around this is to set it up so that your Sims save location is linked to your Dropbox or OneDrive.

- Ensure The Sims 4 is closed and then within File Explorer, navigate to C:\Users\<your_user>\Documents\Electronic Arts\The Sims 4
- Copy the entire 'The Sims 4' folder to your desired location within OneDrive or Dropbox (you should have the program for either of these installed)
- In the start menu, type 'cmd' and click 'Run as administrator'
- Type the following: **mklink /d "[path to cloud service folder]" "[path to your documents folder]"**

e.g. **mklink /d "C:\Users\Oast\OneDrive\Electronic Arts\The Sims 4\saves" "C:\Users\Oast\Documents\Electronic Arts\The Sims 4\saves"**

What this does is creates a symbolic link between your local Sims saves folder and your cloud storage saves folder, so any changes to your save file is also made to your cloud folder. If you do this on both computers then you will always have both of them linked.

It is worth noting that you will need to ensure you have adequate space in your cloud storage (the file size should however be negligible) and that your files are synchronised before playing.

Comment: It is worth noting that you could also likely use Google Drive, but as I have not personally used it and therefore am not certain, I did not mention it in this answer

Comment: I was going to suggest some form of Subversion Repository, but actually Google-Drive or Dropbox are explicitly set up to automatically sync folders like this, so probably a far more effective solution! Good thinking

Comment: I have gone to do what you have suggested, been able to successfully do it one on Laptop, but when I go to do it on my Desktop CMD says "Cannot create s file when that file already exists"
Please can you advise as to how to get around that?
Cheers
Rob